# disable siri permanently in big sur

Tags: macos, software-update, big-sur, siri

Every time my Big Sur Macbook Pro does an automatic overnight update and reboots, it presents a checkbox offering to enable Siri.  Can this perpetual nag be disabled?

(In System Preferences, I leave the checkbox "Enable Ask Siri" unchecked.)

Comment: What "overnight update" would that be?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is via MDM policy.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/siri-restrictions-mdm993369d06/web

If you don’t have an MDM, I recommend trying [JAMF now](https://login.jamfnow.com/) for free since it is supported and free for the first few devices. You can fine tune things like the menu bar as well.

- https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/blocking-siri-on-macos-sierra/

[You might try these profiles as well](https://github.com/rtrouton/profiles/tree/master/DisableSiri) but that operation can be fiddle without the MDM setup completed.

Comment: OK, my macbook is now listed in jamf as an enrolled device, and its system preferences > profiles shows a certificate from jamf.  Now I see contradictory information about how to get and run Profile Manager, which sounds like it's my next step here.  Is that something that I buy from the App Store?

Comment: No, profile manager shouldn’t be needed @CamilleGoudeseune - let me see this weekend if I can try this on my now instance...